# Almost surely convergence of translations of a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $\alpha_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$.

> **Question.** Is there a bounded measurable function $f$, say $1$-periodic, such that  $f_n(x)=f(x-\alpha_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ for any $x$ in  some set $A$ of positive Lebesgue measure?

This of course is not the case when $f$ is continuous, or when its  set of discontinuities has measure zero. In fact such a function, if it exists, must have support on a totally disconnected set of the real line.

**Edit:** If such $f$ exist, then considered as a function on $\mathbb{T}$ one would have
$$ \|f_n-f\|_{L_1(\mathbb{T})}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
and so, every subsequence fo $f_n$ would have an almost surely convergent subsequence; which makes $f(x)$  very sensitive to small variations of the argument $x$.

Comment: Note that a non-zero constant function $f$ answers affirmatively to the question as it is. Could you clarify? What is $x$ etc.

Comment: I think maybe he means “for almost every $x$, $f_n (x)$ fails to converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your precise question, but the almost-everywhere convergence of a subsequence essentially follows from the continuity of the translation operator $t \in \mathbf{R} \mapsto [\tau_t f: x \mapsto f(x-t)]$ in the $L^p$-spaces, for $p < \infty$. For this it is sufficient to have $f \in L^p(\mathbf{R})$. Although this isn't quite the case for you, the question can be reduced to this.

Comment: @LeoMoos: I was typing an edit to the posting when your comment came in. I am aware of the smoothness of the translation operator in $L_p$. That is what would make $f$ somewhat strange. It was suggested to use $f=\mathbb{1}_F$, where $F$ is a fat Cantor set. The the problem would be to see that $F\cap \limsup_n(F-a_n)$ has mass less that $m(F)$.

Comment: Related on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920408/convergence-in-norm-but-not-almost-everywhere-of-f-t-n-f-cdot-t-n-to-f/4042931#4042931, though this constructs a specific sequence instead of starting with an arbitrary one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These questions boil down to questions about maximal inequalities. If you define $(T_nf)(x)=f(x-\alpha_n)$, then maximal inequalities are concerned with the operator $Mf(x)=\sup_n |T_nf(x)|$ and the finite approximations $M_nf(x)=\max_{k\le n}|T_kf(x)|$.

One then asks whether the (non-linear) operator $M$ is bounded in the "weak $L^1$ norm" (which is not a norm at all!). The weak $L^1$ norm of a function $f$ is $\|f\|_{1,\infty}:=\sup_t t\cdot\lambda\{x\colon |f(x)|\ge t\}$ (that is the area of the largest rectangle under the graph). A key example of something with finite weak $L^1$ norm, but infinite $L^1$ norm is $f(x)=\frac 1x$ (which clearly has weak $L^1$ norm 1).

A weak $L^1$ *maximal inequality* is an inequality of the form $\|Mf\|_{1,\infty}\le C\|f\|_1$ for all $f\in L^1$. One can show (as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28997/does-anyone-know-an-intuitive-proof-of-the-birkhoff-ergodic-theorem/45250#45250)) that if a weak $L^1$ maximal inequality is satisfied, then the set of $f$ for which $T_nf$ converges pointwise to $f$ is an $L^1$ closed set. Since for continuous functions $T_nf$ converges pointwise to $f$, and continuous functions form a dense set, if a weak $L^1$ maximal inequality is satisfied, it follows that $T_nf$ converges pointwise to $f$ for all $f\in L^1$.

The converse is also true: if there is not a weak $L^1$ maximal inequality, then there are $L^1$ functions for which $T_nf$ does not converge pointwise to $f$. This is based on (for example) taking positive $f_j$'s of $L^1$ norm $2^{-j}$ so that $Mf_j$ is of weak $L^1$ at least norm $2^j$. Summing the $f_j$'s gives a counterexample.

In this case, it is not hard to see that there is no weak $L^1$ maximal inequality: suppose that the $(\alpha_n)$ are strictly decreasing (this is not essential, but simplifies things). Let $N\in\mathbb N$ and let $\delta<\min_{i\le N}(\alpha_i-\alpha_{i+1})$. Then if $f$ is the indicator function of an interval $J$ of length $\delta$, then $M_Nf$ takes the value 1 on $\bigcup_{i=1}^N(J+\alpha_i)$. By the choice of $\delta$, these intervals are disjoint, so we see that $\|Mf\|_{1,\infty}\ge N\|f\|_1$ for this $f$.

In your question, you asked for a bounded function. You can do this in the same way, but you have to tinker with the construction by hand to make sure it does the right thing.

**Edited to add details of (unbounded) $L^1$ counterexample**

You can pick out a subsequence of the $\alpha_n$'s so that $\alpha_n<\frac 12\alpha_{n-1}$. Clearly if you don't have pointwise convergence along this sequence, nor do you have pointwise convergence along the full sequence.

Let $k$ be given. If $f$ is the indicator function of an interval of length $\alpha_{4^{k+1}}$, then $T_{4^k}f,\ldots, T_{4^{k+1}-1}f$ are disjointly supported. $\|\max_{4^k\le j< 4^{k+1}}T_jf\|_{1,\infty}=3\cdot 4^k\|f\|_{1,\infty}$.

Now if you take $g_k$ to be a randomly chosen sum of $3^{-k}/\alpha_{4^{k+1}}$ translates of $f$, you obtain a function of norm $3^{-k}$ where for each $x$, the probability that $\max_{4^k\le j< 4^{k+1}}T_jg_k$ is not 1 is $(1-3^{-k})^{3\cdot 4^k}$, which is microscopic. Hence $g_k$ is very likely to give you "hits" when you apply $T_j$'s in the range $4^k$ to $4^{k+1}$. Summing the $g_k$'s, you get a function giving hits in all of these ranges.

Comment: I would like to answer by analogy. There is a standard analysis example of a sequence of functions that converges in measure to 0, but not pointwise. Something similar is happening here. The $g$ is the sum of a bunch of $f_j$, each supported on a collection of microscopic intervals. Then the $T_nf_j$ are disjointly supported for all sufficiently small $n$. The result of this is for each $n$, $T_ng$ is close to $g$ for most $x$'s. But, for a.e. $x$, there are lots of $n$'s where $T_ng$ is picking up mass from the spikes.

Comment: @AntonyQuas: Thanks for the explanation of counter example specific to $T_nf=f(\cdot-\alpha_n)$. My question was more about paragraph "The converse is also true: If there is no weak ..." I thought the construction there was about proving that  "$T_nf\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty }T_*f$  point wise ($T_n$ general $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ bounded operators) imply weak Maximal inequality"  as in  [D. L. Burkholder](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00531684) or [Swayer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970516?origin=crossref&seq=1). If it was, I could not see why $T_ng\nrightarrow g$ a.s.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I'm not sure I understand your comment here. I agree I was a bit vague in the paragraph you reference. I don't know the exact conditions under which the failure of a maximal inequality implies failure of pointwise convergence. However, Sawyer's paper that you reference is good enough for your example: your operators are distributive in Sawyer's sense, so the fact that they fail to satisfy a maximal inequality implies that there is not pointwise a.e. convergence.

Comment: What I was trying to say is in the aforementioned paragraph I tough you were presenting a proof that almost surely convergence implies a weak type maximal inequality. As I just learn, that is false but in some interesting cases it works ( Stein, Swayer for finite measures under some conditions). But all this stuff the you may know very well. I also found a real line result for $T_nf:= f*\mu_n$ where $\mu_n$ are measures with compact support, the OP being the particular case $\mu_n=\delta_{\alpha_n}$. This is in Stein's Harmonic Analysis p. 441.

Comment: Good to know. Actually I don’t know this area super-well.